# Ubuntu Ethernet is recognized and connected but internet is not working

Tags: ethernet, wired

Wifi works but the Ethernet wired connection does not. The same cable on the
same computer on the same Ethernet port works perfectly under windows 10. In
Xubuntu 18.04 I get no internet. The system recognizes the Ethernet cable as
soon as I plug it. And the network manager shows that the computer is connected
to the wired connection. However, I am can't connected to the internet through the Ethernet cable (I can connect through Wifi).

[Spoiler alert: the problem was that my laptop was configured with a fixed IP address at work and could therefore not connect at home].

Any help is much appreciated. Here is some diagnostic information. I provide output for: 1) ping, 2) ifconfig, 3) iwconfig, 4) lspci -v, 5) lshw -C network, and 6) /etc/network/interfaces**

**1) ping -c 3 www.xubuntu.org**

```
PING web-frontends.canonical.com (162.213.33.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 150.108.84.253 icmp<sub>seq</sub>=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 150.108.84.253 icmp<sub>seq</sub>=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 150.108.84.253 icmp<sub>seq</sub>=3 Destination Host Unreachable

&#x2014; web-frontends.canonical.com ping statistics &#x2014;
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2051ms
pipe 3
```

**2) ifconfig**

```
 enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 150.108.84.253  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 150.108.84.255
         inet6 fe80::9f88:372b:9863:b493  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 54:ee:75:df:3d:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 576  bytes 82397 (82.3 KB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 460  bytes 45228 (45.2 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
         device interrupt 16  memory 0xed200000-ed220000  

 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
         RX packets 9735  bytes 1008676 (1.0 MB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 9735  bytes 1008676 (1.0 MB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.1.148  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
         inet6 fe80::589f:e92d:cf61:af77  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether f8:34:41:99:9c:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 14579  bytes 6474018 (6.4 MB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 10322  bytes 3798947 (3.7 MB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**3) iwconfig**

```
 wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Netgear 04_5G"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 2C:FD:A1:62:70:54   
           Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:on
           Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:267   Missed beacon:0
```

**4) sudo lspci -v**

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T570
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at ed200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

**5) sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 54:ee:75:df:3d:f8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:126 memory:ed200000-ed21ffff
```

**6) /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.  At work they had assigned a fixed IP address to my wired connection.  The solution was merely to remove that address and tell the network manager to automatically assign an IP address generated by my router at home (i.e., use the Automatic DHCP method to connect).